# setuptools does not install the setup requirements

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I have a machine where the current setuptools version (51.3.3) breaks.
Downgrading back to 50.0.3 works fine.

I tried installing my setup with `"setup_requires==50.0.3"`, however this seems not to work.

Example run:

```
virtualenv -p python3.6 venv > /dev/null; . venv/bin/activate; pip freeze --all | grep setuptools; pip install -e . --force-reinstall > /dev/null; pip freeze --all | grep setuptools
setuptools==51.1.0
setuptools==51.1.0
```

where this is my setup.py:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(setup_requires='setuptools==50.0.3')
```

As you can see, nothing changes. Is there something wrong with my setup code?

---

I'm debugging the `setuptools/__init__.py` module. It seems I get to `_install_setup_requires` and indeed the requirement I passed is there. It just doesn't install...

---

I verified it happens with not only `setuptools` (also happened to me I gave "`jedi==0.17.2"` as a setup_requires)

Comment: `setup_requires=['setuptools==50.0.3']`? AFAIK it should be a list, even if there's only one build-time req.

Comment: Also, if you expect `pip` to downgrade `setuptools` when you add it to `setup_requires`, this won't happen - `setup_requires` lists build-time requirements, which are not installed at all and are only temporarily available while e.g. `setup.py install` or `setup.py bdist_wheel` etc. are executed. Add it to `install_requires` instead - this is a list of dependencies to be installed alongside the package.

Comment: I actually tried install_requires after that, and it worked. Logically I thought that it was the place of setup requires to do that